# Find next factor of KnownNat given a starting KnownNat at type level

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I'm working on some Haskell code and I want to define a type that takes two `KnownNat` and results in the smallest factor of the second `KnownNat` that is greater then the first.

For instance given the numbers `13` and `100` the result would be `20` since `20` divides `100` cleanly and there is no number between `13` and `20` that divides `100` cleanly. Another example is given `96` and `10000` the result would be `100`.

The way I wanted to express this in Haskell is to somehow use the [typelits](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html) package to compute it. But I can't really figure out how.

```
type a b = ...?
```

Any help or pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't be too hard. The standard trial-division algorithm, lifted to the type level, seems to do the trick.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

type FactorGT a b = FactorGTRaw a b (CmpNat (Mod b a) 0)

type family FactorGTRaw a b v where
    FactorGTRaw a b EQ = a
    FactorGTRaw a b _ = FactorGT (a+1) b
```

Try it out in ghci:

```
> :k! FactorGT 13 100
FactorGT 13 100 :: Nat
= 20
> :k! FactorGT 96 1000
FactorGT 96 1000 :: Nat
= 100
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there some kind of tutorial I can follow so I can understand this better? I never really seen the possibility of just lifting a function to the type level.